# How to find sum of engagement_time_msec for different sessions performed by users in bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

My data looks like this:
[image]

For a particular "event_params.key" = "ga_session_id", I want to find the sum of "event_params.value.int_value" when "event_params.key" = "engagement_time_msec".
This is to be done for every user (column - "user_pseudo_id").

The "engagement_time_msec" is present in only "event_name" = "screen_view" and "user_engagement" and can come multiple times for one particular "ga_session_id".

Basically, "ga_session_id" is the unique id for every session a "user_pseudo_id" creates. I want to find the average session duration for the users.

Please help me.

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: Your question just makes no sense.  What key value pair are you trying to look at?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really hard to follow.  You seem to want something like the sum of `engagement_time_msec`:

```
select t.user_pseudo_id,
       sum(case when ep.key = 'engagement_time_msec' then ep.value.int_val end)
from t left join
     unnest(event_params) ep
     on 1=1
group by 1;
```

I have no idea what the other keys are for.  This appears to have the data you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [UNNEST](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#unnest) to extract data from array of key-value pairs in BigQuery:

```
WITH unnested_table AS (
  SELECT
    user_pseudo_id,
    (SELECT value.int_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'ga_session_id') as ga_session_id,
    (SELECT value.int_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'engagement_time_msec') as engagement_time_msec
  FROM myDataset.myTable
  WHERE event_name in ('screen_view', 'user_engagement')
),
session_duration_table AS (
  SELECT
    user_pseudo_id,
    ga_session_id,
    SUM(engagement_time_msec) as session_duration
  FROM unnested_table
  GROUP BY user_pseudo_id, ga_session_id
)
SELECT
  user_pseudo_id,
  AVG(session_duration) as avg_session_duration
FROM session_duration_table
GROUP BY user_pseudo_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
select user_pseudo_id, avg(session_time_msec) as avg_session_time_msec
from (
  select user_pseudo_id, 
    (select value.int_value from e.event_params where key = 'ga_session_id') as ga_session_id,
    sum((select value.int_value from e.event_params where key = 'engagement_time_msec')) as session_time_msec
  from `project.dataset.table` e
  group by 1, 2
)
group by 1
```